# How to filter array of objects when something is searched?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, search, filter, vuejs3

I'm very new to vue and javascript
everything I type in those 3 inputs and then click on submit button is stored in sellBill array that is defined in data.
I want some function that show me in console if something I have searched is in sellBill.
this code in the part "filter" and "search button" has too many problem.

I try to push everything I search into an array called searchBox and then compare with data we have stored before in sellBill among the found function.

this is my HTML code:

```
<div id="app">

    <input v-model="customers" type="text" placeholder="customers">
    <input v-model="productName" type="text" placeholder="productNameا">
    <input v-model="price" type="number" placeholder="price">

    <button @click="addMessage()">submit</button>

    <input v-for="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="search...">
    <button @click="found()">search</button>

    <hr>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>customers</th>
            <th>productName</th>
            <th> price</th>
            <th>activities</th>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="(item, index) in sellBill">
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.customers">
                <p v-else>{{item.customers}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.productName">
                <p v-else>{{item.productName}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.price">
                <p v-else>{{item.price}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button @click="remove(index)">delete</button>

                <button v-if="item.edit === false" @click="item.edit = true">edit</button>
                <button v-else @click="item.edit = false">submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        {{total()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my script:

```
const {createApp} = Vue

    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                customers: "",
                productName: "",
                searchBox: [],
                sellBill: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            addMessage() {
                let x = (this.price)
                if (typeof x === 'number') {
                    this.sellBill.push({
                        customers: this.customers,
                        productName: this.productName,
                        price: this.price,
                        edit: false
                    })
                    this.customers = ''
                    this.productName = ''
                    this.price = ''
                } else {
                    this.price = ""
                    alert("The field is empty or The price must be number")
                }
            },
            remove(index) {
                this.sellBill.splice(index, 1)
            },
            total() {
                let sum = 0
                for (let i = 0; i < this.sellBill.length; i++) {
                    sum += (this.sellBill[i].price)
                }
                return sum
            },
            found() {
                this.searchBox.push({
                    searchItem: this.customers,
                })
                this.customers = '';
                const find = this.sellBill.filter(el => el.customers === this.searchItem || el.productName === this.searchItem)
                console.log(find)
            }
        }
    }).mount("#app")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to codes below:

```
<template>
<div><input v-model="searchKeywords"/></div>
<table >
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in (searchKeywords.length>0?searchResultArr:sellbill)">
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.customers">
                <p v-else>{{item.customers}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.productName">
                <p v-else>{{item.productName}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" v-if="item.edit === true" v-model="item.price">
                <p v-else>{{item.price}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button @click="remove(index)">delete</button>

                <button v-if="item.edit === false" @click="item.edit = true">edit</button>
                <button v-else @click="item.edit = false">submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data:{
     sellbill:[],
     searchKeywords:'',
  },
computed:{
  searchResultArr(){
    if(this.searchKeywords.length>0){
      return this.sellbill.filter(e=>(e.customers.includes(this.searchKeywords) || e.productName.includes(this.searchKeywords)))
    }else{
      return []
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
```